# Need a common email account service used by multiple people

Tags: email, multi-user

I am need of a service which could be used by multiple users for a single email account, something like support ticketing system. But I don't need it for customer support purpose.

My requirements are:

1. Should have a single email account e.g xyz@example.com
2. Multiple users of company example.com can access this email account
3. Any user of this email account can reply and read email threads
4. Whomsoever replies, his name must go in email that who has replied to this email.

I have seen services like zendesk, freshdesk but they are more of customer support desk oriented. I need it for B2B communication, for users of company working in different shifts, so that they can get easily synchronized.

Is there any website which provides such service?

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't just give all these individuals the password, to be able to log into the one email address?  You could either instruct everyone to put their name in the signature at the end of each message they write from this email address, or you could have everyone install Thunderbird; in Thunderbird, in the account settings, you can define a nickname, so to speak.  (I think this might be possible in other email clients as well, such as Outlook.)

Comment: This is what we are doing right now, but it is difficult to enforce things this way. There could be a possibility that someone might forget to put signature or may be he put signature of wrong person to deceive. That is why we need a separate account for every person, so that we have a correct log of all communications.

Comment: Do you understand my Thunderbird idea?  Each person's installation of Thunderbird would have their own account settings.

Comment: Yes I got that, please clarify one scenario. If employee X replies to an email, will employee Y will be able to see what X has replied in that thread or not?

Comment: I would think it would show up in the Sent box.  Why don't you install Thunderbird and see what you think?